# Qt QByteArrays + 16 bit unsigned ints

Tags: qt, kinect

I am playing with depth data from a Kinect sensor, which is a 16 bit unsigned integer array. In order to get rid of some cruft info, I need to bit shift the contents of one pixel three to the left. The results I am receiving are far too small, and weird (example, the numbers printed out should be ~400, as it is a distance in millimetres, but I am getting numbers 0-30).

```
castedBuffer = (uchar*)internalFrameArray->constData();
std::cout << (int)((unsigned short int)castedBuffer[307000]>>3) << "\n";
```

I am struggling because I get the data out in (uchar*) format (which is 8 bits), and my theory is that the bit shift is only being applied to one half of the 16 bit number.

I am a bit lost!

Comment: `castedBuffer[307000]` is an `uchar`, casting it to a wider type won't read more data from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mat's comment, `castedBuffer[307000]` is an `unsigned char`.  If you want to get a 16-bit value out of `castedBuffer`, you'll need to access both `castedBuffer[306999]` and `castedBuffer[307000]`, assuming that the value is big-endian encoded (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Here's a big-endian example of how you would extract a 16-bit value out of the array (assuming you need a 3-bit left shift):

```
castedBuffer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(internalFrameArray->data());
unsigned short int extractedValue = static_cast<unsigned short int>(
                                       ((castedBuffer[306999] << 5) & 0xff60) |
                                        (castedBuffer[307000] >> 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt has a QDataStream class the does precisely what you want: endianness conversions and extraction of integers of arbitrary width from a QByteArray. Here's how to do it:

```
#include <QtCore/QByteArray>
#include <QtCore/QDataStream>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

void test(QByteArray internalFrameArray)
{
  QDataStream str(&internalFrameArray);
  str.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
  // the above must match endianness in the Kinect data stream
  str.skipRawData(306999);
  quint16 val;
  str >> val;
  qDebug() << val>>3;  
}
```